# Может ли быть отрицательным целочисленное представление IP адреса?

Tags: ip, java

написал код кастующий целочисленное представление IP адреса в строковое,

если в метод передать отрицательное число, то он всёравно возвращает валидный ip адрес.
проблема ли это?

```
 public static String parseIP(long input) {                                    
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 24; i != -8; i -= 8) {
        buffer.append((input >> i) & 0xFF);
        if (i != 0) buffer.append('.');
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, чтобы мы смогли сказать что-то более определённое.

Comment: Угу, всё верно. Комментарий avp объясняет почему (превращу его в ответ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно, все `IP` адреса большие чем `127.255.255.255` будут отрицательными целыми 32-бит числами.

Вообще-то в системе (она же на Си написана) `IP` считаются `unsigned`, но (насколько помню) в Java их просто нет (char - unsigned, но 16 бит).

Не знаю, о каком методе какого класса Вы говорите, но если с IP не заниматься арифметикой (и сравнениями на больше-меньше), то никакой проблемы нет.

Comment: @MaxBel, в самом деле, погуглив удивился, насколько плохо в Java обстоит дело с тривиальной `inet_ntoa()`. 

(По сути, именно ее Вы реализуете в своем  `parseIP(long input)`)

IMHO все можно свести к одной строчке, предоставив оптимизацию компилятору

    public static String inet_ntoa(long ip) {
         return "" +  (ip >> 24) & 0xff + "." + (ip >> 16) & 0xff + "." + (ip >> 8) & 0xff + "." + ip & 0xff;
    }

Comment: мда.. что-то я не додумался до такого простого и локаничного решения(